# Regex in Visual Studio: How to comment out all lines that contain "xyz"?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, using Regex, how do I comment out all lines containing the text "xyz"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:^.{.*xyz.*}$\n
With the Replace textbox left blank.

Answer (score 7):

```
Find what: ^.*xyz.*

Replace with: //\0
```

use: Regular expressions.

Comment: Hmm.. doens't seem to work. It works if the entire like is `xyz`, but not if `xyz` is only part of a line.

Comment: @Billy, works exactly the same as yours in 2010 rc, which is not surprising, since it is in fact the same as your, without the redundent set of grouping parenthesis!

Comment: Hmm.. something went really crazy then. I could have swore the regex listed was `^.xyz.` which would not do what the OP needs. The *s are not optional :P

Comment: In VS2019 it's //$1 instead of //\0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846263/295011

Answer (score 2):

```
^(.*xyz.*)$
```

Replace with

```
// \0
```

Should do the trick I think. (Not 100% positive here... testing now)

EDIT: Fixed (it's \0 not \1).

Billy3