# Comment out found lines in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

I'm looking in my c# Code for Lines that contain the following term :

> System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight

I want to set a comment mark ( `//` ) in front of each line that contains the term using Find&Replace Function of VisualStudio.

Do you guys know of a quick way to do that?

Comment: Find all "System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight", Replace with "//System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight"?

Comment: Replace System.Drawing.Sys... with // System.Drawing.Sys...

Comment: Well , but theres gonna be more text infront and after the term...

Comment: Do a find all, then go to each line and comment it. Since you don't exactly know what each line containing your 'System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight' will look like, coming up with any kind of regex will probably take longer than doing the manual labor.

Comment: You can always search for `System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight` and replace for `/*System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight*/`

Comment: "more text in front and after the term" you should give some possible cases of how this term can be embedded in text. So if you have a line like : `string n = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight.Name;` you want the `//` in front of `string n` did I get you right?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

- `Text to find` -> **`^(.*System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight.*)$`**
- `Replace with` -> **`//$1`**
- Use RegEx search option -> **`.*`** *or* **`[x] Use Regular Expressions`**

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open Find & Replace.

Find "`System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight`"
and replace it with "`// System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight`".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Regular Expression.

Search for: `(^.*System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight.*)$`
Replace with: `//$1`

Comment: Updated.  I was using Notepad++ to test.  Whoops!